# Custom 24-hour single-hand watch face for Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, ui, watchos

Is there a way to make the Apple Watch display a 24-hour single-hand watch face? Preferably with midnight on the bottom, and noon at the top?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Someone designed one on this thread: https://twitter.com/gohnjanotis/status/1053294837494112256

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to Apple Watch faces, one is limited to [customizations](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/customize-the-watch-face-apdb0c5fb937/watchos) as per what Apple allows.

App Store Review Guidelines restrict app developers from creating custom watch faces.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality

> **4.2.4** Apple Watch apps that appear to be a watch face are confusing, because people will expect them to work with device features such as swipes, notifications, and third party complications. Creative ways of expressing time as an app interface is great (say, a tide clock for surfers), but if your app comes too close to resembling a watch face, we will reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a Solar Dial face that is practically the same as a single arm 24 hr. face.

[image: Close-up of the solar dial face by apple]

[image: Solar Dial. This watch face features a 24-hour, circular dial that tracks the sun as well as an analog or digital dial that moves opposite to the sun’s path.]

[Link to faces (watchOS 9)](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/faces-and-features-apde9218b440/watchos)